# Android Virtual Device on Virtual Box

Tags: android, ubuntu, virtualbox, android-virtual-device

ist it possible to run AVD on VirtualBox?
I have Ubuntu 14 installed on it.
I have downloaded new Android Studio but with a bit obsolete tools 25.2.5 what allows to use "android" command.
I have created such AVD:

```
Available Android Virtual Devices:
Name: AVD1
Device: Nexus 6 (Google)
Target: Android 4.0.3 (API level 15)
Tag/ABI: default/armeabi-v7a
Skin: 1440x2560
```

When I launch it i can see only black screen and nothing happens.
I heard that it's not possible to run AVD on emulated operation system, but don't know if it's true. Is there any solution to overcome this problem?
And if not, what you would reccoment then? Should I find some online emulator, test on phycial device or maybe install AVD on my host system (Windows), and test on Windows. But i don't know if I can take file generated on Ubuntu and test on Windows??
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Genymotion runs in VirtualBox, yes, but the AVD should work the same way. Why are you running an emulator in an emulator, though?

Comment: It's a good point. I wanted to develop hybrid mobile app wrapped with cordova on Ubuntu. Maybe I should just install Ubuntu on my computer,, instead of creating VM. But I have all environment ready except Android emulator so would prefer to stay here for now

Comment: You can mount a shared folder for your project in VirtualBox, and run the generated apk in Windows. Or if possible, put Cordova on your windows installation

Comment: IIt seems that this Genymotion is not free so ok, maybe I will try to mount a shared folder and test on Windows, becasue I am beginner and to be honest I spend to much to to set up this environent that i already want tostar coding, not spend more time setting up.

Comment: I was trying to set up a clean environment completely contained in a Virtual machine on Windows to do my Android development a couple of years ago, at that time I wasn't able to get the emulator to work inside Virtual Box. Outside Virtual Box it worked though

Comment: Genymotion is free, but you need an account